# JPA OneToMany cascade with abstract entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an abstract entity and its subclasses

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(JOIN)
public abstract class Foo { /* ... */ }

@Entity
public class Bar extends Foo { /* ... */ }

@Entity
public class Baz extends Foo { /* ... */ }
```

and a class with a list of `Foo`s:

```
@Entity
public class Qux {

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL)
    List<Foo> foos;

}
```

But when I `merge(qux)` I get

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: Foo
```

Which it's strange, since I have `cascade = ALL`. So I tried to change it to `cascade = MERGE`, and the error changes to

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: Foo
```

How can I make this relation work? (I'm on Hibernate 5.2.7)

Comment: Well in your case, you don't need `cascade = ALL` because it's too broad here, your specific situation requires the `SAVE_UPDATE` cascade type, try to change it to `cascade = SAVE_UPDATE` or use the annotation `@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})`.

Comment: I'd like to stay JPA compliant, while `@Cascade` is not. But I still don't understand why this is happening…

Comment: You are describing the behavior of a missing `cascade` option in `@OneToMany`, but having `cascade = ALL` or `cascade = MERGE` should avoid this.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have flushmode auto turned on, causing the persistence context to flush before you have setup all your references and called merge- such as attempting to read in your existing entities and setup the associations between them and the new instance. Make sure you are reading in Foo from the current context, or explicitly calling merge on it (and use the managed instance) before setting up your references

Comment: Please post the entire Hibernate stack trace.